# Clojure: Calling function from script throws RuntimeException

Tags: clojure

i'm newbie to clojure world coming from python background.

i have created a clojure script **problem_1.clj**:

```
(defn first_element
 [arg]
 (println arg))

(first_element [1, 2])
```

i have installed clojure via **sudo apt-get** and running script as

**>> clojure problem_1.clj**

error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: first_element in this context, compiling:(/home/naveen/Code/repos/clojure-scripts/problems/problem_1.clj:6:1)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you have a namespace macro call above this code? Pretty sure that's mandatory. Underscores also typically aren't used. Use dashes instead.

Comment: no, i do not have macro call. This is all i have in a file.  using dash.

Comment: I've never tried running a clojure file without a namespace macro call. They're easy to do; they're just like Java's package declarations, only they also "contain" any imports/requires you have. Add `(ns problem-1.clj)` to the very top of the file.

Comment: And btw, when I said use dashes instead of underscores, I meant within the code itself. By Java conventions, the filename *must not* contain a dash. Also, you typically shouldn't use commas when defining a vector. They're optional, but you'll really only see them when defining a complicated map/dictionary.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the Clojure package from APT; it's outdated. For one-off scripts, use something like [Boot](http://boot-clj.com/).

Comment: @Carcigenicate (ns problem-1.clj) worked, thanks.

Comment: @navyad Good to hear. I posted an answer. If you plan on writing Clojure, I recommend using Intellij Community edition with the Cursive plug in. It gives you at the very least a REPL and debugger. Cursive also has structural editing, which is a huge pain to learn to use correctly, but it lets you wrote clojure like Python, where indentation indicates nesting; so you don't need to manually manage parentheses.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a call to the namespace macro as the very first thing in your file. The namespace should match the name of your file, except that the namespace should use `-`s, while the file **must** not contain dashes; use `_`s instead. The namespace should also be qualified by any enclosing namespaces; although that's not applicable here.

Add `(ns problem-1.clj)` to the top of your file, and check out [its documentation](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ns)